# How do I swap the Run/Walk toggle in first person mode in GTA V on PC?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v, mods

When in 3rd person mode, my character walks by default and jogs when I press [Shift], on first person mode, my character jogs by default and walks when I press [Shift]. How do I make it so that the first person acts like the 3rd person view where I walk by default? I want to enjoy the scenery in first person and not always have to run. Plus, I often accidentally run into people instigating them to fight me.

Is there a mod or setting file I can edit for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so while waiting for answers here, I searched some more and I think I found the answer. [Simple Foot Controls](https://www.gta5-mods.com/scripts/simple-foot-controls) seems to be the mod I'm looking for. I've been testing it out and I don't see anything wrong so far.